# how to make marble veins 3d, like in real marble rocks?

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural, texture-coordinates

So, just like trees have layers that follow a previsible path, marble rocks have this vein like array of impurities giving it its looks.
Thing is, I'm trying to texture a model like a marble piece was just milled into, it's a pot cap.
For reference, I'm trying to recreate this object in the image below.

[image: Example]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTzk9T06gdw

Comment: Well if you just google "procedural marbles in blender" you will find what you're looking for and if you get stuck on a certain step of having a particular problem, you can ask it here.

Comment: Thanks for the response bqbaka!
I've actually tried some ways of doing this, but those feel like the texture is just wraping around the uv and not a part of something, fell what I'm saying?

Comment: Not really. Could you elaborate?

Comment: There are also a lot of marble textures out there, may be one of them would suit you? Or may be you just want to tweak the mapping?

Comment: Yeah, the problem ain't the texture in itself, but understanding the nodes.
What I mean is, trees and marbles have layers that in case of the tree is different parts of it's "skin" and the marble has this impurities in it.
I want to create something that when you cut just like a tree or marble, will show the profile of that skin part or impuritie.
Like when you chop a tree and there's aways that pattern inside the wood...
I guess I'm just rephrasing all I said, was that good?
I could make some pictures to ilustrate.

Comment: Let me put it another way.
I know something about nodes, watched lots of tutorials, but lack some of the specific ways things work.
In nodes there are 1D, 2D, 3D, and 4D noise textures.
I can't understand how the dots and noises are formed in each one (I do know what differs 4D from 3D, but can't see the picture of the texture in 3D, because it is aways a 2d image in a plane.
How I understand it is that the 3D noise textures have lots of spheres in it, and thought I could shape those to look like patches of impurities inside the marble. (Maybe using object cordinates or something.)

Comment: I kinda get what you are trying to explain. I'm not sure about the method to achieve that, tho.